# GitHub Pages site works on mobile but not desktop?

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

My github pages site with a custom domain works just fine on mobile but when i try to access the same URL from desktop i get a **DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN** error. Any ideas why this may be ? The site can be found here if it helps [Site](https://www.carefreeautomation.com)

EDIt: it works with this [link](https://carefreeautomation.com) which does not include 'www.' if this makes my problem any clearer

Comment: used vpn and site opened on desktop as well

Comment: Does [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1679326/513903) solve it for you?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that it shows on your mobile, DNS records doesn't return anything [WhatsMyDNS](https://www.whatsmydns.net/#NS/www.carefreeautomation.com)

Comment: it does show on mobile, i updated the question a little bit. turns out it shows when i omit 'www.' from the URL

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that you've got your DNS server up correctly.? I did a lookup for your domain name and it doesn't appear that you've got your CNAME pointing to GitHub pages. To do so, add a CNAME record to your domain via your domain registrar's dashboard. This should point to the name of your GitHub pages url (ex. john.github.io/xyz). You can read up on this more [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site#about-custom-domain-configuration).

Comment: im fairly certain I do, i edited the question to provide some more info. hope it clears things up a little bit

Answer (score 0):

I notice you say that it doesnt work if you add the `www.`. I'm not exactly sure why this is (there's not enough information to say why). I'm guessing you did not correctly set up the record, so here's what it should look like:

```
@     A     4H     127.0.0.1
```

<sub>(You may change the TTL and IP, of course)</sub>

I'm guessing you forgot the `@` in the first field, which puts it under both `www` and the root subdomain. If this is not the case, you can attempt to fix this issue by adding `www` in a separate record to easily resolve the problem.

```
www     A     4H     127.0.0.1
```

Note that this will work for both `CNAME` and `A` records.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe desktop dns server is not so fast to fetch changes.

Change dns server in desktop connection settings for a public google's 8.8.8.8. For windows that's going to be Control Panel > Network and sharing center > Change adapter settings > Right click adapter (in my case it was WIFI) >  Choose connection (Internet protocol Version 4) > Click Properties > Select "Use the following DNS server addresses" > Enter 8.8.8.8 in "Preferred DNS server" > Click OK

Answer (score -2):

I am a newbie in the field and faced the same issue. Came here to find the solution. I just did plug out the ethernet and connected my laptop to my wifi and it worked.

Comment: Very unlikely that there is a difference between fixed connection and wireless connection. Most likely it took you enough time to do so that your browser's cache timed out and the browser asked for a new version from the server.